# Styling <data:title/> in blogger

Tags: html, css

I need to change this original line of code in blogger layout HTML/CSS to make the blog title red

```
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:title/></a>
```

vaguely understanding what I was doing and spending 150 minutes on experimenting I managed to get what I wanted with either of these 2 codes:

```
<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><h1 style='color: #ff0000'><data:title/></h1></a>

<a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><span style='color: #ff0000'><data:title/></span></a>
```

is there another way to make the title red without adding `<h1 ... or  <span...`  code?

or

is it possible to style this  `<data:title/>`  part of this particular line of code?

(I know this is a dumb question)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps - see below.

(html)

```
<a expr:href="data:blog.homepageUrl" class="title"><data:title/></a>
```

(css)

```
a.title {
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I was hoping that others would respond.